# Electrical ,what voltage to use

Tags: electrical, wire, generator, cables, transformer

I am confused about what voltage to use to calculate current for cable size of transformer.
for example, single phase given load 140kva 120/240. 
if  I=140/120v= 1166 A  and if  140/240v=583A
I know for fact, we use I=kva/1.73 x V. But for single phase i am not able to find correct solution.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a **home** improvement question.

Comment: Your home, maybe!    Seriously, for single phase, there's no factor, you take V x A = VA.  240vx200a=48kva.  If you have triple that power, I'm guessing you take your flash water heaters seriously.

Comment: + wolf , 1.73 is a 3 phase factor used in 3 phase calculations. Single phase is just VxA as @wolf Harper said. Current in the primary is approximately equal to Currrent in the secondary. So you can use the primary voltage or secondary voltage to do your calculations.

Comment: The formula is I = (KVA x 1000) / Voltage  The voltage is line to line or line to neutral whatever the highest secondary voltage is. The units all divide out and you are left with amps.

Comment: The KVA must be multiplied by 1000 or your answer will be in Kiloamps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this question is here as it's not a DIY process, but I'll answer anyway.

Three phase power (208/120 or 480/277) is divided by the square root of 3 and by the higher voltage. The square root of 3 is used because of the adjustment between phases.

Single phase power is completely different, and easier. You just divide by the higher voltage, 240. This is because 120 is not the voltage on the panel; 120 is simply a subdivision because of the neutral.

Comment: Despite the URL, the topic here is home improvement, not DIY. Pro questions are also explicitly within scope as long as they're on that topic. Industrial wiring wouldn't be.

Comment: I mentioned DIY because Tester101 already mentioned home improvement above. I don't believe it fits here either. Sizing of cables for a single phase transformer? Sounds more like a homework problem than anything since there is a 'given load'